# Media Query capturing everything with two styles

Tags: android, css, html, media-queries

My display has two basic styles. One with two boxes left and right and one with two boxes on top of each other. My goal is simply to set my media queries so that all situations are grouped into the appropriate setup (of these two options).

For some reason, this setup is displaying on my nexus 6 with the "big" setup, despite the fact that it should be displaying on the little setup. What is messing up...

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 1px) and (max-device-width: 800px)" href="SmallStyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 801px) and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 800px)" href="SmallStyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 801px) and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 3000px)" href="BigStyle.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using 1 css file with media queries inside like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
//code here
}
```

Comment: Only because I find it easier to keep things straight this way.

Comment: Then try to remove the device-width options. Like this:

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 800px)" href="SmallStyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 3000px)" href="BigStyle.css">